# How to write a "UPSERT" query for Orientdb in .net, C#?

Tags: c#, .net, orientdb, upsert

I am trying to write a query in .net for orient db and I am not sure if the API supports UPSERT as is in the documentation.

Comment: It looks like API supports UPSERT. do you want an example ? http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/SQL-Update.html

Comment: `orientdb> UPDATE Client SET id = 23 UPSERT WHERE id = 23`  Updates the record if it exists . Otherwise inserts the record.

Comment: Yes venky, an example would be great! thanks!

Comment: which OrientDB Driver you are using for .NET ?

Comment: I am using the following driver OrientDB-Net.binary.Innov8tive.0.1.4 Also my use case is to create a new node if it doesnt exist else update the current node.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421083/is-it-possible-to-work-with-orientdb-using-c

Comment: Are you sure it works with the graph? the API shows compatibility with document DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can give you an example of **`UPDATE / UPSERT`** with **`C#`**.
The following code creates a new `TestDatabaseName` database and relative classes (`Users`) and properties (`userID`) otherwise, if the database already exists, it executes the **`UPDATE / UPSERT`** command.

**C# CODE:**

```
using System;
using Orient.Client;

namespace Stack37995408

{

    static class Stack37995408

    {

        private static string _hostname = "127.0.0.1";
        private static int _port = 2424;
        private static string _rootUserName = "root";
        private static string _rootUserPassword = "root";

        private static OServer _server;

        private static string _DBname = "TestDatabaseName";
        private static string _username = "root";
        private static string _password = "root";
        private static string _aliasDB = "myTestDatabaseAlias";

        static void Main(string[] args)

        {

            _server = new OServer(_hostname, _port, _rootUserName, _rootUserPassword);

            if (!_server.DatabaseExist(_DBname, OStorageType.PLocal))

            {

                _server.CreateDatabase(_DBname, ODatabaseType.Graph, OStorageType.PLocal);

                Console.WriteLine("Database " + _DBname + " created");

                //Connect to the DB

                OClient.CreateDatabasePool(
                    _hostname,
                    _port,
                    _DBname,
                    ODatabaseType.Graph,
                    _username,
                    _password,
                    10,
                    _aliasDB
                );

                Console.WriteLine("Connected to the DB " + _DBname);

                using (ODatabase database = new ODatabase(_aliasDB))

                {

                    //Classes and properties creation

                    database
                        .Create
                        .Class("Users")
                        .Extends<OVertex>()
                        .Run();

                    database
                        .Create
                        .Property("userID", OType.Integer)
                        .Class("users")
                        .Run();

                    //Populate the DB

                    OVertex vertexUser = new OVertex();
                    vertexUser.OClassName = "Users";
                    vertexUser
                        .SetField("userID", 1);

                    OVertex createVertexUser = database
                        .Create.Vertex(vertexUser)
                        .Run();

                    Console.WriteLine("Created vertex " + createVertexUser.OClassName + " with @rid " + createVertexUser.ORID + " and userID " + createVertexUser.GetField<int>("userID"));

                }

            }

            else

            {

                //Connection

                OClient.CreateDatabasePool(
                    _hostname,
                    _port,
                    _DBname,
                    ODatabaseType.Graph,
                    _username,
                    _password,
                    10,
                    _aliasDB
                );

                Console.WriteLine("Connected to the DB " + _DBname);

                using (ODatabase database = new ODatabase(_aliasDB))

                {

                    database
                        .Update()
                        .Class("Users")
                        .Set("userID", 2)
                        .Upsert()
                        .Where("userID")
                        .Equals(2)
                        .Run();

                    Console.WriteLine("Operation executed");

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

**First execution (DB, classes, properties and first vertex creation):**

**Output:**

```
Started Thread 4320
Database TestDatabaseName created
Started Thread 7184
Connected to the DB TestDatabaseName
Created vertex Users with @rid #11:0 and userID 1
Started Thread 4368
```

**Studio Output:**

[image]

**Second execution (I try to update a vertex with `userID = 2` but the `UPSERT` command creates it because it doesn't exist):**

**Section:**

```
database
    .Update()
    .Class("Users")
    .Set("userID", 2)
    .Upsert()
    .Where("userID")
    .Equals(2)
    .Run();
```

**Output:**

```
Started Thread 6172
Started Thread 7244
Connected to the DB TestDatabaseName
Operation executed
Started Thread 5860
```

**Studio Output:**

[image]

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot! it does help. So what if I want add more parameters to "where" clause? Could I do that?

Comment: Hi @Howard Roark, yes this is a simple example but, if you want, you could add more parameters (more `.Set()` to set multiple fields, `.And()` after the `.Where()` clause to check multiple conditions, ecc...). Hope to have been helpful.

Comment: Just the last question, .And() takes parameters. What parameters are those?

Comment: In my case I used only `userID` but if you had, for example, another field called `name` you could check that (or the `@rid`, `@class`,..) in this way: `.And("name").Equals("name...")`...

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, though can we include subquery in this kind of object mapping? for eg. I want to do this. create edge contact from (select from xyz where lastname = "abc" To (select from firm where firstname ="xyz");

Comment: It's difficult to say, I had no chance to try it...but you could try it by using the `.Query()` method. If you're looking for further detailed informations, I advise you to take a look at the [Orient.NET wiki](https://github.com/yojimbo87/OrientDB-NET.binary/wiki). Glad to have been helpful.